# javascript open indirect URL link in new tab

Tags: javascript, url, tabs, indirect-objects

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $('.tablepress-id-??').on('click', 'tr', function() {
        var $a = $(this).find('a').last();
        if ($a.length) window.location = $a.attr('href');
      });
    });

 </script>
```

The above works 100% perfectly to open url link when anywhere in a table row is clicked [using a url link in an image that's also in each row] - the link opens in the same tab/window though and I need it to open in a new tab/window.

I've read a few similar threads but they're not exactly the same situation and nothing I am trying to adapt from those is working [I may be placing the additional code in the wrong place in my existing one?]

Assistance from anyone who knows what they're doing in this area - ie not me :) - would be hugely appreciated ...

Comment: Skip the JS, and use the anchor with `target="_blank"` attribute.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your response, and I do already have the anchor image open like that, if just the small anchor itself is clicked! The JS renders the entire table row 'clickable' - the whole cell that the anchor is in and the adjoining cell with related text in it...that it does this is my starting point :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($a.length) { 
  var url = $a.attr('href');
  window.open(url, '_blank');
}
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks so much for your response - this is sort of what I had been playing around with, with no luck - I think I might be using this in the wrong place? In relation to my original code, where exactly in it would you put the code that you have given?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript"> jQuery(document).ready(function($){ $('.tablepress-id-1').on( 'click', 'tr', function() { var $a = $(this).find('a').last(); if ( $a.length ) window.location = $a.attr('href'); var     url = $a.attr('href'); window.open(url, '_blank'); } ); }); </script>                       I've added it as above and this opens the link in a new tab, excellent :-) But it also opens the link on the origin page - any suggestions on what to amend so that it only opens in the new tab and not the original page as well? Thanks heaps again for the code and your time :)

Comment: I figured it out, thanks so much for the original code! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can find some useful documentation for location object here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location

As you can see this is the same,

```
location.assign("http://www.mozilla.org"); // or
location = "http://www.mozilla.org";
```

But to the assign function you can pass it the [target](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp) attribute, '_blank' for new tab like this:

```
window.location.assign('https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location', '_blank')
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me HOWEVER, I don't know code, just troubleshot some, because I had this EXACT problem.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.tablepress-id-1').on( 'click', 'tr', function() {
        var $a = $(this).find('a').last(); 
        if ( $a.length ) 
        var url = $a.attr('href'); window.open(url, '_blank'); 
 } );
})
</script>
```